# Biblioteca de funções em Xcode (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Estou precisando criar uma biblioteca de funções em `Objective-C`.

A ideia é criar algo mais ou menos como a biblioteca de funções **Math.h**. Isto é, não é necessário instanciar a classe para utilizar os métodos declarados nessa classe (ou biblioteca).

Como deve ser implementada a classe para que atenda estes critérios?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em **Objective-C** temos dois tipos: *`instance methods`* e *`class methods`*. Com estes métodos, o seu arquivo de cabeçalho (**.h**) fica mais ou menos assim:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

- (void)instanceMethod;
+ (void)classMethod;

@end
```

Note os sinais `+` e `-`.

Em poucas palavras, o que chamamos de *`instance method`* tem a necessidade de ser executado a partir da instância de uma classe que você criou. Por outro lado, o que chamamos de *`class method`* (em outras linguagens este pode ser chamado de **método estático**) não tem a necessidade de instanciar a classe para executar este método.

Podem ser usadas desta maneira:

```
[MyClass classMethod];

MyClass *object = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[object instanceMethod];
```

Nos estudos de orientação à objetos, é possível encontrar informações mais complementares.

Por outro lado, sendo **Objective-C** uma "derivação" de **C**, você pode simplesmente declarar seu método como abaixo, sendo necessário somente fazer a importação onde é que for utilizar:

```
int calcular(int foo, int bar) {
    return foo + bar;
}
```

E a utilização:

```
int res = calcular(2, 2);
```

Comment: Paulo, obrigado pelo retorno.

Tem alguma forma de não precisar referenciar a classe?

Por exemplo: 

classMethod;

Comment: Complementei minha resposta com essa informação.

Comment: Muito bom. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Se tiver respondido sua pergunta, considere marcar como resposta aceita, assim ajuda outros com esta mesma dúvida.